# Почему не видит изображение?

Tags: html

Почему не видит файл?             /////////
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напиши вот такой путь до изображения

```
 ../img/cover.img
```

Comment: src="../img/cover.jpg" так работает

Comment: ну я так же и написал, только src опустил за ненадобностью

Comment: и как совет, разберись почему не работает как сделал ты, пойми почему так нельзя делать